# Set a custom ELContext in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

this question is related to a previous answer to a similar problem, which would fit my requirements.

[Programmatically register taglib reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214371/programmatically-register-taglib-reference)

I understand the solution, but I'm not able to figure out how to register my custom ELContext (or FunctionMapper) to the current FacesContext (or ELContext) without a specific implementation (MyFaces, mojarra etc.). The goal is to use some functions in the `*.xhtml` source. I DON'T want to use a taglib because some dynamic stuff should be handled by my own function mapper.

So how do I register a FunctionMapper or decorate the current ELContext with my own implementation?

Cheers,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

Register it in `faces-config.xml` as

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>com.example.YourELResolver<el-resolver>
</application>
```

Comment: I thought only ELResolver are allowed to be registered as a ELResolver. And this Interface does not allow me to add a custom FunctionMapper.